# Loop through an object's properties and get the values for those of type DateTime

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I have a list of objects (Cars). For each car in the list I need to loop through it and find any properties of type `DateTime`. If I find a property of `DateTime` I need to get the value and do a time conversion. For now lets just print out the `DateTime` property value to the console. I am having issues understanding what I need to put in the first parameter of the `prop.GetValue` function. Any help would be appreciated!

```
foreach (var car in carList)
{  
    foreach (PropertyInfo car in car.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        var type = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(prop.PropertyType) ?? prop.PropertyType;
        if (type == typeof (DateTime))
        { 
            Console.WriteLine(prop.GetValue(???, null).ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 165, accepted):

You need to use `car` as the first parameter:

```
foreach (var car in carList)
{  
    foreach (PropertyInfo prop in car.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
         var type = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(prop.PropertyType) ?? prop.PropertyType;
         if (type == typeof (DateTime))
         { 
             Console.WriteLine(prop.GetValue(car, null).ToString());
         }
    }
}
```