# C# How to add values of all variables of an object to a list?

Tags: c#

I have a Class that contains some strings:

```
public class Headers
{
    public string FirstStaticColumn { get; set; }
    public string ItemFrom { get; set; }
    public string PinFrom { get; set; }
    public string TerminalFrom { get; set; }
    public string CableLabel { get; set; }
    public string WireLabel { get; set; }
    public string CrossSection { get; set; }
    public string ItemTo { get; set; }
    public string PinTo { get; set; }
    public string TerminalTo { get; set; }
    public string CableEndsleeve { get; set; }
    public string LengthMM { get; set; }
}
```

Now I need all values of these Properties and store them in a list.

Is there a faster way than doing

```
Headers headers = new Headers(); /*Let's pretend that all Variables have a value now*/
List<string> list = new List<string>();

list.Add(headers.FirstStaticColumn);
list.Add(headers.ItemFrom);
list.Add(headers.PinFrom);
...
```

Comment: The way you have it is fine. Another option would be to add a property to Headers that returns an `IEnumerable<string>` of property values. Then `list.AddRange(headers.NewPropertyNameHere);`

Comment: Have you considered Reflection?  It may or may not be appropriate depending on why you are doing this and how much control you need over the list.

Comment: Faster, no, more concise, yes; you could use reflection.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36656177/loop-through-an-objects-properties-and-get-the-values-for-those-of-type-datetim/36656271

Answer (score 1):

There is a marginal speed improovement if you do this instead:

```
string[] array1 = new string[] { headers.FirstStaticColumn, headers.ItemFrom, headers.PinFrom };
```

On the one hand, it is in [Speed Rant](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/) territory of difference. On the other hand, unless you *keep* adding to the list, you are just wasting resources without a point, by not staying with a basic array.

I can not agree with the commenters advise for reflection. Reflection is definitely slower and should only ever be used as a fallback, not your first choice. If writing the code is impossible (unknown input types) or unfeasible (too many input types), I see it as valid. But in the shown case? I see no reason to resort to reflection.

Comment: I also do not recommend reflection for this.  Huge performance hit, relatively speaking.  +1

Comment: If the OP didn't want an array, then setting the capacity of the `List` would give a similar speed improvement.

Comment: @mjwills Agreed.  And for those that want the code, it's the constructor for `List<T>` that accepts an int to size the underlying array.  This suggestion avoids unnecessary array resize and copying.

Answer (score 1):

Using reflection, you can achieve it like

```
Headers headers = new Headers(); /*Let's pretend that all Variables have a value now*/
List<string> list = new List<string>();
foreach (var item in headers.GetType().GetProperties())
{
  list.Add(item.GetValue(headers)?.ToString());
}
```

Yes, it will have a performance hit but this way it won't required to be maintained whenever you add new property to `Headers` class

Comment: I can only repeeat that using refleciton here is both slow and propably unessesary, given the shown case. Everything you need to do, you know to do at compile time. Headers does not look like the type that will suddenly grow some extra properties. I could maybe see reflection used on the grounds of "it would be a lot of work to write that and I might forget to update it later". But then I am really biased against reflection.

Comment: 100% agreed @Christopher, demonstrated the use of reflection if someone finds it helpful. May be they have the header class in multiple files as partial, and maintained by multiple developers.

Answer (score 1):

You *could* do something like this.

Is it less verbose?  Not really.  The advantage I would say is refactoring the functionality into the class itself which may or may not be desirable.

I edited the property names and count for brevity.

```
public class Headers
{
    public string A { get; set; }
    public string B { get; set; }
    public string C { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<string> GetPropertyValues()
    {
        yield return A;
        yield return B;
        yield return C;
    }
}
```

I could make this code less verbose and "maintenance free" via reflection, but I personally wouldn't take the performance trade-off.

But if you want to use reflection, this works:

```
public class Headers
{
    //You can modify this to get certain properties if you want, like public only
    private static readonly PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(Headers).GetProperties();

    public string A { get; set; }
    public string B { get; set; }
    public string C { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<string> GetPropertyValues()
    {
        foreach (var prop in properties)
            yield return prop.GetValue(this)?.ToString();
    }
}
```

There is a slight advantage to other reflection approaches by caching the `PropertyInfo` array.  But again, reflection is slow.