# Looping through a list and find all the ID of the properties:

Tags: python, json, api, loops, python-requests

I'm a newbie in Python. I have a project of collecting data on API call. I've successfully called for a list of data (List of users and other info such as ID, name, etc.) based on this post: [Loop through an object's properties and get the values for those of type DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36656177/loop-through-an-objects-properties-and-get-the-values-for-those-of-type-datetim/36656271).

The code I wrote looks like this:

```
import requests
import json
def get_all_time_entries():

url_address = "my url"  
headers = {
    "Authorization": "Bearer " + "my api",
    "Harvest-Account-ID": "my ID"
}


all_time_entries = []

# loop through all pages and return JSON object
for page in range(1, 15):

    url = "my url"+str(page)
    response = requests.get(url=url, headers=headers).json()        
    all_time_entries.append(response)       
    page += 1

# prettify JSON
data = json.dumps(all_time_entries, sort_keys=True, indent=4)

return data
print(get_all_time_entries())
```

I've managed to get a list of users of this format:

```
{
        "created_at": "2021-01-23T22:34:30+07:00",
        "email": "someone.gmail.com",
        "id": 11111,
        "integration_id": null,
        "login_id": "someone.gmail.com",
        "name": "Name of user",
        "short_name": "Name of user",
        "sis_import_id": 111,
        "sis_user_id": "Name of user",
        "sortable_name": ", Name of user"
    }
```

Now I want to make a loop to get all the `ID` properties in the `all_time_entries()` list and put them in another list. How do I do this?

Comment: Is it possible? Yes. I suggest using a list comprehension.

Comment: The question you linked to is a C# question, not a Python question.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the "page += 1" at the end of the loop each iteration the value of page is assigned at beginning to its corresponding range value, to get all ids do this:

```
all_ids = [i['id'] for i in all_time_entries]
```

Answer (score 0):

The following function will do what you want

```
get_ids_from_time_entries(time_entries):
    ids = []

    for entry in time_entries:
        ids.append( entry['id'] )

    return ids
```

And then you would use it like so

```
time_entries = get_all_time_entries()
ids = get_ids_from_time_entries(time_entries)
print(ids)
```